# Regex to match file extension

Tags: java, regex

I have file names separated by colon `:`

This one is working as expected

```
String fileName = "test.pdf:test1.txt:test2.png:test3.jpg:test4.jpeg:test5.doc";
String ext = "pdf";
System.out.println(fileName.matches(".*\\b\\."+ext+":\\b.*"));
```

but when a matching file is at the end, above solution does not work

```
String fileName = "test1.txt:test2.png:test3.jpg:test4.jpeg:test5.doc:test.pdf";
```

What is the regex to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the pattern to look for `:` or the end `$`:

```
".*\\." + ext + "(:|$).*"
```

(Also, I removed the unnecessary `\\b`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern and matcher.

```
Pattern pdfPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.pdf");
if(pdfPattern.matcher(fileName).find()){
    System.out.println("Found PDF");
}
```